# python for-loop parallelization using multiprocessing.pool

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
def calc_stuff(x,a,b,c):
    ...
    return y
x = range(N)
y = zeros(x.shape)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(nprocs)
    y = p.map(calc_stuff,x,a,b,c)
```

This does not work, and as I searched online, it is because the map function deals with iterables rather than argument lists. I wonder what's the simplest method to modify this code to parallelize it, i.e., x is the array/iterable that I want to parallelize.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `itertools.repeat` with `zip` (or `itertools.izip`) to build your multiple arguments into an iterable of tuples and then use `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap` to call the function with the tuple unpacked as arguments:

```
from itertools import repeat

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(nprocs)
    y = p.starmap(calc_stuff, zip(x, repeat(a), repeat(b), repeat(c)))
```

Comment: Isn't starmap is itertools? p.starmap gives me errors: 'Pool' Objects has no attribute 'starmap'

Comment: Oh, apparently `starmap` was added to the `Pool` class in Python 3.3, so it won't work for you in 2.7. Perhaps you could modify your worker function to take a tuple and unpack it into the individual variables? `def calc_stuff(tup): x, a, b, c=tup`...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which can turn the function with those required arguments that you don't want to iterate over, into a new function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import functools

def calc_stuff(a,b,c, x):
    return x+a+b+c

N = 10
x = list(range(N))
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nprocs = 4
    p = Pool(nprocs)
    calc_stuff_p = functools.partial(calc_stuff, a, b, c)
    y = p.map(calc_stuff_p, x)
print(y)
```

results in

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Note that your iterable `x` now comes last in `calc_stuff`, since the function returned by `partial` appends any arguments to the existing list of arguments.